# Saving unique log for each test class using TestNG framework and Log4J

Tags: java, maven, log4j, testng

I have an automation project (Java, Maven with TestNG, log4j).
I am trying to create log file foreach test class (LoginTest would create LoginTest.log, HomeTest would create HomeTest.log , etc), I have implemeneted my own logger mechanism for this purpose but at the end of the run I am getting only the last class test log file (for the last test class that ran).

This is my logic:

```
    public class TestLogger extends LoggerFormat {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private static final ZoneId DEFAULT_ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of(EnvConf.getDefaultTimeZone());
    private final ThreadLocal<Map<String, List<String>>> testsLogMap = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void info(ITestContext context, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.info(msg);
        log(Level.INFO, context, msg);
    }

    public void error(ITestContext context, Throwable t, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.error(msg, t);
        log(Level.ERROR, context, msg, t);
    }

    public void error(ITestContext context, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.error(msg);
        log(Level.ERROR, context, msg);
    }

    public void warn(ITestContext context, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.warn(msg);
        log(Level.WARN, context, msg);
    }

    public void warn(ITestContext context, Throwable t, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.warn(msg, t);
        log(Level.WARN, context, msg, t);
    }

    public void debug(ITestContext context, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.debug(msg);
        if (LoggerFactory.isDebug()) {
            log(Level.DEBUG, context, msg);
        }
    }

    public void debug(ITestContext context, Throwable t, String messageFormat, Object... args) {
        String msg = handleFormatMsg(messageFormat, args);
        super.debug(msg, t);
        if (LoggerFactory.isDebug()) {
            log(Level.DEBUG, context, msg, t);
        }
    }

    private void log(Level level, ITestContext context, Object message, Throwable t) {
        message = String.format("%s\n%s", message, throwableToString(t));
        log(level, context, message);
    }

    private void log(Level level, ITestContext context, Object message) {
        Map<String, List<String>> logsMap = getLogsMap();
        if (!logsMap.containsKey(context.getName())) {
            logsMap.put(context.getName(), new ArrayList<>());
        }

        logsMap.get(context.getName()).add(formatMsg(message, level));
        if (level.toInt() != Level.DEBUG.toInt()) {
            Reporter.log((String) message, 0);
        }
    }

    private static String formatMsg(Object message, Level level) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now(DEFAULT_ZONE_ID);
        return String.format("[%s][%s]%s",
                TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.format(dateTime),
                level, message);
    }

    public List<String> getAndDeleteLogsByTest(String testName) {
        return getLogsMap().remove(testName);
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getLogsMap() {
        if (testsLogMap.get() == null) {
            testsLogMap.set(new HashMap<>());
        }
        return testsLogMap.get();
    }


    private static String throwableToString(Throwable t) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (StackTraceElement traceElement : t.getStackTrace()) {
            builder.append(traceElement.toString()).append('\n');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }


    private static String handleFormatMsg(String message, Object... args) {
        if (args.length == 0 && message.contains("%")) {
            message = message.replaceAll("%", "%%");
        }
        return String.format(message, args);
    }
}
```

this is my BaseTest Class:

```
@Listeners({NeoTestListener.class})
public class BaseTest {

    private static final Browser BROWSER = Browser.valueOf(EnvConf.getProperty("ui.browser.type"));
    private static final File SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER = new File(EnvConf.getProperty("test_output.screenshots.folder"));
//    private static final File DOWNLOADS_FOLDER = new File(EnvConf.getProperty("workspace.tests.downloads"));
    private static final File DOWNLOADS_FOLDER = new File(EnvConf.getProperty("test_output.logs.folder"));
    private static final String ADMIN_USERNAME = EnvConf.getProperty("hackeruso.admin.user.email");
    private static final String ADMIN_PASSWORD = EnvConf.getProperty("hackeruso.admin.user.password");

    protected static DriverWrapper driver;
    protected LoginPage loginPage;
    protected Date testStartTime;
    protected ITestContext context;
    protected TopBar topBar;
    protected final File testTempFolder;

    static {
        if (!SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER.exists()) {
            FileUtil.createFolder(SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER, true);
        }

        if(!DOWNLOADS_FOLDER.exists()) {
            FileUtil.createFolder(DOWNLOADS_FOLDER, false);
        }
    }

    protected static String randSuffix(String prefix){
        return prefix + "_" + String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()).substring(9);
    }

    public BaseTest() {
        this.testTempFolder = new File(DOWNLOADS_FOLDER, randSuffix(getClass().getSimpleName()));
        FileUtil.createFolder(testTempFolder, false);
//        testTempFolder.deleteOnExit();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public final void baseSetup(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        this.context = context;
        driver = DriverWrapper.open(BROWSER, DOWNLOADS_FOLDER);
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        info("<!!! '%s' START !!!>" , context.getName());
        testStartTime = new Date();
        this.context.setAttribute("test_start_time", testStartTime);
        info("testStartTime=[%s]" , testStartTime);
    }

    private void printBrowserLog() {

        List<LogEntry> serverLogLines = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).getAll();
        if (serverLogLines.size() > 0) {
            Log.i("<---------Browser [SERVER] log start--------->");
            for (LogEntry entry : serverLogLines) {
                Log.e(entry.toString());
            }
            Log.i("<---------Browser [SERVER] log end------------>");
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public final void baseTeardown(ITestContext context) {
        Date testEndTime = new Date();
        if (driver != null) {
            printBrowserLog();
            driver.quit();
        }
        info("<!!! '%s' END !!!>" , context.getName());
        info("testEndTime=[%s]" , testEndTime);
    }

    public static DriverWrapper getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    protected void info(String message , Object...args){
        TESTS_LOG.info(context , message , args);
    }

    public void error(Throwable t , String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.error(context , t , messageFormat , args);
    }

    public void error(String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.error(context , messageFormat , args);
    }

    protected void warn(String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.warn(context , messageFormat , args);
    }

    public void warn(Throwable t ,String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.warn(context , t , messageFormat , args);
    }

    protected void debug(String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.debug(context , messageFormat , args);
    }

    public void debug(Throwable t , String messageFormat , Object...args) {
        TESTS_LOG.debug(context , t , messageFormat , args);
    }
}
```

And this is my listener:

```
public class NeoTestListener implements ITestListener {
    private final File SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER = new File(EnvConf.getProperty("test_output.screenshots.folder"));
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_HH_mm_ss");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat LOG_NAME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_HH_mm_ss");
    private static final File TESTS_LOGS_FOLDER = new File(EnvConf.getProperty("test_output.logs.folder"));

    static {
        if (!TESTS_LOGS_FOLDER.exists()) {
            FileUtil.createFolder(TESTS_LOGS_FOLDER, true);
        }
    }

    private static String getTestMethodName(ITestResult iTestResult){
        return iTestResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getName();
    }

    @Attachment
    public byte[] saveFailureScreenShot(DriverWrapper driver){
        return driver.getScreenshotAsByte();
    }

    @Attachment(value = "{0}", type = "text/plain")
    public static String saveTextLog(String message){
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
        context.setAttribute("WebDriver", getDriver());

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        TESTS_LOG.info(result.getName() +" " +  result.getTestClass() );
//        TESTS_LOG.info("[Test: " + getTestClassName(result.getTestContext())+ " Started]");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        TESTS_LOG.error(String.format("I am in onTestFailure method:=[%s] failed", getTestMethodName(result)));
        Object testClass = result.getInstance();
        DriverWrapper driver = getDriver();
        takeScreenshot(getTestMethodName(result));

        //Allure ScreenShot and SaveTestLog
        TESTS_LOG.info(String.format("Screenshot for class=[%s], method=[%s]", getTestClassName(result.getTestContext()), getTestMethodName(result)));
        saveFailureScreenShot(driver);
        try {
            saveLogTextFile(result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saveTextLog(getTestMethodName(result) + " failed and screenshot taken!");
    }

    @Attachment
    private byte[] saveLogTextFile(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        return saveToLogFile(result.getTestContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedWithTimeout(ITestResult result) {
    }

    private void takeScreenshot(String filePrefix){
        File dest = new File(SCREENSHOTS_FOLDER , filePrefix + "_" + FOLDER_NAME_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + ".png");
        takeScreenshot(dest, getDriver());
    }

    private void takeScreenshot(File destFile, DriverWrapper driver){
        File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAsFile();
        Path src = Paths.get(scrFile.toURI());
        Path dest = Paths.get(destFile.toURI());
        try {
            Files.copy(src, dest , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            TESTS_LOG.info("[[ATTACHMENT|" + destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "]]");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            TESTS_LOG.error("Failed to save screen shot at file: " + destFile.getName());
            TESTS_LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private byte[] saveToLogFile(ITestContext context) throws IOException {
        File logFile = createLogFile(context);
        boolean created = FileUtil.createNewFile(logFile);

        if(created){
            List<String> testLogLines = TESTS_LOG.getAndDeleteLogsByTest(context.getName());
            if(testLogLines == null){
                TESTS_LOG.error(context, "test=[%s] don't have any log lines!" , context.getName());
            }else{
                FileUtil.writeToFile(logFile.getAbsolutePath(), testLogLines);
            }
        }else{
            TESTS_LOG.error(context, " failed to create test log file=[%s]", logFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(logFile);
    }

    private static File createLogFile(ITestContext context){
        return new File(TESTS_LOGS_FOLDER, String.format("%s_%s.log",getTestClassName(context), LOG_NAME_FORMAT.format(context.getStartDate())));
    }

    private static String getTestClassName(ITestContext context){
        return context.getAllTestMethods()[0].getInstance().getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

}
```

This is a sample of class test in my environment:

```
public class ForgotPasswordTest extends BaseTest {
    private String verifyEmailURL = "";
    private static final String AUTOMATION_EMAIL= EnvConf.getProperty("automation.email.user");
    private static final String AUTOMATION_EMAIL_PASSWORD=EnvConf.getProperty("automation.email.password");
    private static final String AUTOMATION_WEBAPP_USER = "AUTOMATION_TESTER";
    private  ResetPasswordPage rpp;
    private final static String NEW_PASSWORD = "1Qaz2wsx3edc";
    private final static String ENVIRONMENT_BASE_URL = EnvConf.getProperty("base.url");

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        topBar = new TopBar(driver);
        rpp = new ResetPasswordPage(driver);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void navigateToLoginPage(){
        loginPage.navigateAndVerify();
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void sendChangePasswordInstructions() {
        ForgotPasswordPage fpp = loginPage.clickAndVerifyForgotPasswordButtonAction();
        fpp.sendForgotPasswordInstructions(AUTOMATION_EMAIL);
        Assert.assertTrue(loginPage.getForgotMsgAlertText().contains("Thank You, An Email Has Been Send"));
        info("Sending forget password instructions phase is successful!");
    }

    @Test(priority=3)
    public void verifyEmail(){
        verifyEmailURL = "";
        String regex = "href=\"([^\"]*)" ;
        String from = "<SOME_URL>";
        String subject = getSubject();
        String msg = MailHelper.getMessagesFromGmail( AUTOMATION_EMAIL, AUTOMATION_EMAIL_PASSWORD, from, subject, testStartTime);
        Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(msg);
        while (pageMatcher.find()) {
            if (pageMatcher.group(1).contains("reset-password")) {
                verifyEmailURL = pageMatcher.group(1);
                verifyEmailURL = ENVIRONMENT_BASE_URL.concat("/").concat(verifyEmailURL.split("/")[3]);
                info("Verify URL: " + verifyEmailURL);
            }
        }

        info("Verifying email address is successful!");

    }

    @Test(priority = 4)
    public void navigateToResetPasswordScreen(){
        navigateTo(verifyEmailURL);
    }

    @Test(priority=5)
    public void connectToUpdateNewPassword() {

        rpp.changeNewPassword(NEW_PASSWORD);
        info("Changing password is successful!");
    }

    @Test(priority=6)
    public void verifyPasswordChanged() {
        signIn(AUTOMATION_EMAIL, NEW_PASSWORD, true);
        assertTrue(topBar.verifyExistenceTopBarNavigationItem(TopRightNavBarItem.SUPPORT));
        info(String.format("Password for user=[%s] changed successfully", AUTOMATION_WEBAPP_USER));

    }

    private String getSubject(){
        return "Reset Password";
    }

}
```

Every time I run my program using `mvn clean test` I am not able to save the log for each test class it always saves me the last test class that was run and other log files not saved as expected.

what is missing ? I tried to search for a solution and tried various actions but I did not get the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The [Maven Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) has the parameter [`<redirectTestOutputToFile>`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile) which creates the following files  in `target/surefire-reports` in addition with a test project here:

- `igb.so.so65465538.FirstTest-output.txt`:

  ```
  println(): First test...
  22:32:25.537 [main] INFO igb.so.so65465538.FirstTest - log.info():  First test...
  ```
- `igb.so.so65465538.SecondTest-output.txt`:

  ```
  println(): Second test...
  22:32:25.561 [main] INFO igb.so.so65465538.SecondTest - log.info():  Second test...
  ```

Comment: @tupacshakur Add another `<execution>` with another `<configuration>`.